# I don't know what is appcompat v_7 and why is it being add in every time when i create a new project ?

Tags: android

### this code is about the default code of MainActivity.java

having problem to understand and also there is a another thing that is the           fragmentaion_main.xml file which is likely another buden instead of activity_main.xml why it so ?

```
package com.example.onehello;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

 }
```

Comment: what is your minimum sdk version ??

Comment: i don't know would you please tell me how to know this.. :(

Comment: That's not the issue, when you create new project, check the new "Empty Activity" instead of "Blank Activity"

Answer (score 0):

This appears after installation "Android Support Library":
https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html

Answer (score 0):

> #### What is appcompat_v7?

It is the support library added for backwards compatibility. Android has many versions and each new version brings many changes to the API. So, for the older versions of Android to be compatible with the code written for the newer versions, the appcompat_v7 library is helpful.

> #### Why is it being added every time I create a new project?

I assume that you are using Eclipse IDE for the development. Ideally, it would suffice to create one appcompat_v7 folder and make all the projects link to that folder for support library. But, there seems to be some bug in Eclipse. It creates a new appcompat_v7 folder each time a new project is created.

> #### 'fragment_main.xml' is like another burden?

Fragment class was introduced in Android API 11. It is useful in creating different layouts for tablets and phones. It is more of a good support to take advantage of the bigger screens on tablets. If you want to develop your application for a smart phone only, you need not even worry about it. So, it's more of an advantage than a burden.

For more reading on fragments, go to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html